# Удаление из 2х таблиц одним запросом

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы, users и user_gifts.

В каждой таблице есть поле "user_id".

Так вот, возможно ли удалить одним запросом сразу из двух таблиц данные, с условием что user_id одинаковый?

```
DELETE FROM `users`, `user_gifts` WHERE `user_id` = 132;// Так ошибка вылетает
```

Comment: У вас наверняка есть foreign key смотрящий из одной таблицы на другую. Делаете его `ON DELETE CASCADE` и при удалении записи из основной таблицы в подчиненной все удаляется автоматически

Comment: Нет, кючи не ставил, вообще запрос для теста такой написал, у меня есть десяток таблиц в которых нужно удалять записи при удалении пользователя, по его айди.

Comment: Вот сделайте все по грамотному, т.е. сделайте со всех 10 таблиц foreign по user_id с on delete cascade и все. это средство в БД предназначено именно для этого. все остальные способы не гарантируют, что вы не забудете где нибудь что нибудь удалить. ключи кстати можно добавить в любой момент а не только при создании таблиц ...

Comment: Да это можно, я задал вопрос , можно ли как то так удалить как я думал, или нет, про внешние ключи я знаю, стильно модно и удобно.

Comment: Ответ от Venta не подошел ? Просто в большинстве БД это невозможно. В MySQL всякое может быть ... И если это всякое есть, то оно должно выглядеть как ответил Venta

Comment: Ну да, посмотрел доку на MySQL (первое что нашел гугл) можно, причем почти так как сказал Venta http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/delete.html

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так?

```
DELETE FROM users, user_gifts 
WHERE users.user_id = user_gifts.user_id 
AND users.user_id = 132;
```

Comment: Судя по доке `delete users, user_gifts from users, user_gifts where ...`

Answer (score 2):

Вот так. Один запрос из двух через точку запятой:

```
DELETE FROM `user_gifts` WHERE `user_id` = 132; DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = 132;
```

А кто сказал что за раз можно запросить только один запрос?

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек:

Если между таблицами есть отношение(внешний ключ), то можно повесить каскадное удаление.

Удаляя запись из главной таблицы, удаляются все ее потомки.

Еще вариант(Если отношений нет):

Можно повесить триггер. Который перед удалением из главной таблицы, будет удалять всех потомков.

Comment: Да, это знаю, но не ставил внешние ключи.

Comment: Еще вариант добавил.

Comment: Я не использовал внешние ключи)